# How to force correct timezone for Javascript New Date()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I'm trying to get the current midnight date with Javascript and I use this:

```
var mydate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I receive this:

```
Sun Oct 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

The problem is, that it's not British Summer Time anymore, but for some reason javascript still thinks it is. This is messing up my entire application, as I convert this into a timestamp like this:

```
mydate = Math.round(to_day.getTime() / 1000);
```

How can I change this?

Comment: javascript will return the date with your system timezone (GMT+0100) , i think you should just ignore BST part as long the date is correct

Comment: How can I do that? I convert this into a timestamp, and the additional BST hour is added into that.

Comment: My computer's timezone is definitely not set to BST, it's GMT.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will always use your computer's locale to extract the date. It's using BST because this is the timezone that you have set (automatically perhaps?).

You can extract a UTC time *string* by calling the following function:

```
var d = new Date();
d.toUTCString(); // "Sun, 26 Oct 2014 11:46:11 GMT"
```

There are libraries that deal specifically with manipulation of date objects. One such tool I recommend you checkout is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It gives you the option to convert between timezones as well as a whole lot of other useful time/date related features.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - indeed... I don't think I've ever seen that little icon on MDN... Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: When I do this: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0).toGMTString(); I receive "Sat, 25 Oct 2014 23:00:00 GMT". It's not midnight, and so it's not really helpful. And isn't there a way without having to install libraries?

Comment: Also, my computer's timezone is definitely not set to BST.

Comment: Well that's expected - what you are doing here is creating a new date object that represents midnight (in your timezone) and then converting it to UTC.

Comment: JavaScript can only read the time that is given to it. Your browser is telling JS that it's in BST (for some reason).

Comment: If you need to deal with timezones I would strongly recommend *not* re-inventing the wheel and using a library that is already written to handle situations like these... Another alternative would be to use the [`d.getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) value to "fix" the times you are getting back.